# Go Forward several Commits in Netbeans (Git)?

Tags: git, netbeans, version-control, netbeans-7

I'm still relatively new to version control. I'm using Git with Netbeans. I reverted my changes a little too far and now I need to go back? Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

A revert is, itself, a commit. You can revert the revert.

Comment: I reverted the commit once or twice...What happens then?

Comment: Unless you do funky things with `reset` or `rebase`, you can only ever add commits to the commit graph. You can undo an undo of an undo as many times you like, and the repository history will show exactly what happened.

Comment: the revert is failing due to some file

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `git reflog` and find the commit you are fine with, then `git reset <sha1>` to it, where `<sha1>` is the commit you chose from the reflog.

Comment: Accurate. I didn't go into this because it changes history and the OP didn't mention whether (s)he pushed changes.

Comment: if by pushing changes you mean using an external repository than no. I'm using a local repository